# Using HugSQL to INSERT multiple rows at once into PostgreSQL table with ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, clojure, hugsql

I'm working with PostgreSQL and wanting to `INSERT` multiple rows at once with an `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` statement.

I've got something like this:

```
-- :name add-things! :! :n
INSERT INTO my_table (
  p,
  foo
)
VALUES :tuple*:values
ON CONFLICT (p) DO UPDATE
SET my_table.foo = foo
```

where `p` is the primary key.

I call this with:

`(add-things! {:values [[1 1] [2 3]]})`

But this returns:
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column reference "foo" is ambiguous`.

Using `SET my_table.foo = :foo` (with a keyword parameter) leads to `clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Parameter Mismatch: :foo parameter data not found`, because there are no keyword parameters when using the `:tuple*:values` syntax.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Maybe by using Clojure code in the HugSQL query?

Comment: Does `... SET foo = excluded.foo` work?

Comment: SET my_table.foo = my_table.foo

Comment: @cfrick Yes that works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the use of just `foo` inside the conflict resolution.  There is a foo in the "insert data" and one on the actual table.  You need to address the "insert data" somehow to resolve that conflict.  The solution as stated in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) is:

> `conflict_action` specifies an alternative `ON CONFLICT` action. It can be either `DO NOTHING`, or a `DO UPDATE` clause specifying the exact details of the `UPDATE` action to be performed in case of a conflict. The `SET` and `WHERE` clauses in `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and **to rows proposed for insertion using the special `excluded` table**.

So

```
...
SET foo = excluded.foo
```

solves the conflict.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers Does it actually _not_ work with the table alias given?

Comment: Nope not on my machine. It crashes with: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "my_table" of relation "my_table" does not exist`

Comment: I'll trust you on that ;)